# Unix, how to join lines that starts with 15 numbers

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
123456789012345lksdlkssalkd
skdañsldkasñldkas+
slkdñlaskd aslda lkl
012345678901234dkfskadflkdflkasdf
 ASLÑsa sLL SLD   SdsDA
SLDALDK LÑD
SDFSADF
d
345678901234560   DÑLSAD SDLÑSlkfl fg fg kfglkfgklfd gf
lfdld
```

I want have this result, starting each line with those who starts with 15 numbers, and replacing intermediate line endings with a space:

```
123456789012345lksdlkssalkd skdañsldkasñldkas+ slkdñlaskd aslda lkl
012345678901234dkfskadflkdflkasdf  ASLÑsa sLL SLD   SdsDA SLDALDK LÑD SDFSADF d
345678901234560   DÑLSAD SDLÑSlkfl fg fg kfglkfgklfd gf lfdld
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like my solution best: no branches and no sed,

```
awk '/^[0-9]{15}/ && NR > 1 {sep="\n"} \
     {printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep = " "} END {print ""}' dat
123456789012345lksdlkssalkd skdaÃ±sldkasÃ±ldkas+ slkdÃ±laskd aslda lkl 
012345678901234dkfskadflkdflkasdf  ASLÃsa sLL SLD   SdsDA SLDALDK LÃD SDFSADF d 
345678901234560   DÃLSAD SDLÃSlkfl fg fg kfglkfgklfd gf lfdld
```

- Set the separator to a newline anytime you match the 15-digit pattern, except on line 1.
- Print any input line with a leading separator, and set the separator to a space.
- Print a newline at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$ awk '/^[[:digit:]]{15}/{if (buf) {print buf} buf=$0; next} 
                        {buf=buf FS $0} 
       END              {print buf}' file
123456789012345lksdlkssalkd skdañsldkasñldkas+ slkdñlaskd aslda lkl
012345678901234dkfskadflkdflkasdf  ASLÑsa sLL SLD   SdsDA SLDALDK LÑD SDFSADF d
345678901234560   DÑLSAD SDLÑSlkfl fg fg kfglkfgklfd gf lfdld
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks

Comment: Note: with older gawk version < 4, you may need to either use `--re-interval` or `--posix` to use the interval expression `{15}`

Answer (score 1):

can be simplified with the help of `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/[0-9]{15}/\n&/' file | 
  awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n' '$1=$1'

123456789012345lksdlkssalkd skdañsldkasñldkas+ slkdñlaskd aslda lkl
012345678901234dkfskadflkdflkasdf ASLÑsa sLL SLD SdsDA SLDALDK LÑD SDFSADF d
345678901234560 DÑLSAD SDLÑSlkfl fg fg kfglkfgklfd gf lfdld
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;/\n[0-9]{15}/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' file
```

Replace a newline with a space unless that newline preceeds a number of 15 characters.